# how to get default value of stored procedure parameter in java

Tags: jdbc

I need to get the default value assigned to a stored procedure parameter.

I can get all the details of the stored procedure parameters using DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns but I don't find any way to get the default value of a procedure.

For example if I have the below stored procedure

```
create procedure st_test (
@param1 varchar(10),
@param2 varchar(4000),
@param3 varchar(20) = 'SOMEVALUE',
@param4 varchar(30) = 'OTHERVALUE'
@param5 varchar(4000) = NULL
)
```

Then I need to get the default value of param3, param4 & param5 i.e. 'SOMEVALUE','OTHERVALUE' & NULL

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you should be able to retrieve this value using [`DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), field `COLUMN_DEF`. However it is possible that not all drivers support this.

Comment: I tried COLUMN_DEF field, you are right not all drivers support this. I am using sybase jconnect driver and it doesn't support this field :(

I think I will need to do this using sybase specific database query.

Answer (score 0):

However i also couldn't find the best way to do it for SQL server (which i was using )because of following limitations :
1. Using native JDBC DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns does return null :P
2. Using Spring libraries which does only tell parameters names and type but not the default value.
3. Using above information to bind NULL values to these parameters does not help as these NULLs overrides the default values and does disaster to logic inside Procedures.

I did wrote a procedure which returns me whole signature of procedure, it goes like this :

create procedure [dbo].[GetString](@proc_name varchar(100), @string varchar(1000) OUT) as 
DECLARE 
@Val VARCHAR(MAX)
declare @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_helptext @proc_name
SELECT  @Val = COALESCE(@Val + ' ' + Val, Val)
FROM    @Table
select @string = @Val
END

This procedure returns the signature of procedure whose name if passed to it as In Param.
Then i did some Ptocessing on String and got their default values.